# Looking for a story told by intelligent nuclear bombs about the war they had with humanity

Tags: story-identification, warfare, artificial-intelligence, post-apocalyptic

I'm looking for a science fiction short story I read in a magazine about 20 years ago, with a very similar premise to *Dark Star*. The story was narrated by a nuclear bomb that was either sentient or an artificial intelligence and described the war they had fought with humanity. Unfortunately, I can't remember many details, but I remember a few things about it:

1. The story started with the description of a memorial statue of someone.
2. At some point in the story, the bombs had to take refuge on the Moon.
3. They needed hydrogen to recharge their batteries.
4. They were digging the surface of the Moon with their "telescopes".
5. They considered detonation as their ultimate purpose, but were not too keen for it.

I know that these details are vague, but I'm hoping it might ring a bell with someone.

Comment: This is a very well asked story ID question.

Comment: When I read this all I could think of was ST:VOY "Warhead"....

Comment: @Arammil  I was about reading to say the same thing after reading the title.

Comment: I think this came out much more recently, and it's not a short story, but this sounds an awful lot like [Blonde Bombshell](http://www.theguardian.com/books/2011/feb/05/blonde-bombshell-tom-holt-review) by Tom Holt.

Comment: This reminds me of _Lungfish_ by David Brin. But that's about ancient A.I. war machines on a planetoid at the far edge of the solar system contemplating the approach of human explorers, some of the details are weirdly similar though.

Answer (score 9):

The story could be "[Bagatelle](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?51670)" by John Varley. It is in his *[Barbie Murders](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?35518)* collection of short stories and novelettes (also called "picnic on near side").  But I am not sure it is the one you are after because I do not remember details. It does take place on the moon. In "Bagatelle", the bomb is sentient with an organic brain.  Also it was published in 1976 which is a bit early for the date you give.  But it might have been republished.

I highly recommend anything by John Varley. An excellent author, with some style, and a very original and realistic world. With a very personal sense of humor as I recall. I did not realize it, but he seems very under-read for his quality of work. Has been a favorite of mine for a long time.

The full text of Bagatelle is available on [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v37n07_1976-10). Even if it is not what you look for, it is worth reading.

Buy the books too, hopefully he will write more.

Comment: I found that book online, but it wasn't on the Internet Archive, and it wasn't the same as the original question.

Comment: Good that you found it. It may have been on the Internet Archive when I answered. Too long ago for me to remember. I was not sure it was the answer, and said so. But it often happens that we modify or mix stories in our memory, so that there is always a chance of being useful with an answer that does not fully fit. Glad you found the text. I hope you enjoyed it.

Comment: @BrianMinton It's in the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v37n07_1976-10) now.

Comment: No war with humanity in that story.  Just a terrorist who is his own bomb.